# 403 Error in Gitlab connection with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops

I tried connecting Jenkins with Gitlab, while using System hooks in the Gitlab repository.

It is throwing me the following error :

```
Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2Fproject%2FContinious_Integration');

Authentication required Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403 window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2Fproject%2FContinious_Integration'); Authentication required
```

Comment: Also tried connecting with secret tokens, Still getting the same error

Comment: Jenkins global configuration -> require authorization for /project endpoint
Copy userid and API key for a Jenkins user who has authorization to run the job
Create a webhook on GitLab to trigger the job, and use HTTP basic auth: http://user:apikey@gitlab/project/jobname  This worked for me..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Jenkins global configuration` -> `require authorization for /project endpoint`

- Copy userid and API key for a Jenkins user who has authorization to
  run the job
- Create a webhook on GitLab to trigger the job,
- Use HTTP basic auth (Below format)

> user:apikey@gitlab/project/jobname

This worked for me..!